# Can the output layer be connected to multiple layers?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, model-request

Normaly, the output layer is only connected to the second last layer.
Is there any model that the output layer is connected to multiple layers (For example, the second last layer AND the layer before it.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Residual networks have connections that skip layers, the obviously called _skip connections_. I don't know if skip connections also happen for that specific case you're mentioning, but you should look into ResNets because they may be one answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Normaly, the output layer is only connected to the second last layer.

This is only normal for standard MLPs. As soon as you look into slightly more sophisticated neural networks, you'll find a variety of different schemes to connect the layers within a neural network.

> Is there any model that the output layer is connected to multiple layers

There are many examples of such a case, like [WaveNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03499), [U-Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597), [HRNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07919), to name a just few. The first two networks use *skip-connections*. Mostly summation or concatenation is applied to combine the multilayer results.
And like @nbro mentioned in his comment, [ResNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385) is also comparable which uses residual connections to bypass layers.

There are a lot more examples than that because this practice has a very beneficial aspect to it: It shortcuts the backward pass and thus mitigates the [vanishing gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem).

A more general answer to your question is that you can wire up your layers however you want as long as the network stays differentiable. It should somehow make sense though: In the case of Wavenet these skip-connections help to capture temporal features from different granularities (short-term temporal features detected in the early layers / long-term temporal features detected in later layers).